# Max execution time not changing

Tags: php

there are two files in my project, *php.ini* and *php5.ini*

`php.ini` contains `set_time_limit`

and *php5.ini* contained `max_execution_time = 60`, but i have changed it to `max_execution_time = 500`

but when I open phpinfo.php, it still shows max_execution_time = 60

what should i write

I also tried `set_time_limit(500)` in my php.ini

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the **{}** toolbar button.

Comment: In the `phpinfo.php` check where exactly is `php.ini` being loaded from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not recommended to change the **max_execution_time** to higher values server-wide. Simply use the following code before calling *phpinfo()* or the code you need.

```
ini_set ( 'max_execution_time', 5000);
```

**set_time_limit()** simply resets the time limit, you need max_execution_time.

Answer (score 1):

In general I think it is a better idea to use `set_time_limit(60)` or another amount of time you need in those scripts where you actually need more time. That command resets the time limit to its parameter. It will not work in the php.ini.

Also, have you restarted your web server after changing the php.ini? Otherwise your changes might not have taken effect yet.

Answer (score 0):

Search with a `phpinfo();` what is your loaded configuration file and do the change in that file.

Otherwise you can change your time limit with [set_time_limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) function.